# React-native - drawerLabel based on the user location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, asynchronous

I have a react-native application, I need to render a menu item according to the user location, however the function which returns the user location is an asynchronous function and I'm getting an undefined, so my question is how can I set the `drawerLabel` value of the `navigationOptions` based on the user location?

```
static navigationOptions = () => ({
    drawerLabel: () => (OptionsDrawer.isOptionsItemAvaliable() ? 'Options' : null)
})




private static isOptionsItemAvaliable() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((result) => this.setUserLocation(result.coords), ()=> {console.log("Failed to load user location")};
    return verifyUserLocation(userLocation);
}

private static setUserLocation(coordinates){
    userLocation = coordinates; //userLocation is a global variable
}

private static verifyUserLocation(coordinates){
//Code to check the user location and returns if it's inside the allowed area
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the title with a custom component. In the component, you can keep location as a state which you update when the location changes. Something like this:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: <LogoTitle />,
  };
}
```

[Read more here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#replacing-the-title-with-a-custom-component)

Comment: I would like a simpler solution without the need of a new Component.

Comment: I don't see how that would be possible. In my opinion, a component is a simple and clean way to extract logic from the navigator config.